# sql.exception: column not found

Tags: java, sql, ms-access-2010

Hi guys can u tell me what is wrong with my code?
When I set my ResultSet as "SELECT * FROM Table1" it works perfectly,
also if it is "SELECT key, itemName, itemPrice, itemQuantity FROM Table1"
but when I try to use only one of them or two it prints out an error column not found.

My database is stored in MS Acceess. That's my main:

```
try (Connection cn = DBUtil.getConnection(DBType.MS_ACCESS);
    Statement st = cn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT Table1.key FROM Table1");) {

    Table1.displayData(rs);

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    DBUtil.processException(ex);
}
```

and that's Table1.java:

```
public class Table1 {
    public static void displayData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        // to print out my database
        while (rs.next()) {
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            buffer.append(rs.getString("key") + " ");
            buffer.append(rs.getString("itemName") + " ");

            double price = rs.getDouble("itemPrice");
            DecimalFormat pounds = new DecimalFormat("£#,##0.00");
            String formattedPrice = pounds.format(price);
            buffer.append(formattedPrice + " ");

            buffer.append(rs.getInt("itemQuantity") + " ");

            System.out.println(buffer.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if the column is exists in your table or not ?

Comment: Try to debug and see what is the actual SQL statement generated by your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your result set will only contain the columns that you define in your select query. So if you do

```
rs.getString("itemName")
```

then you have to select that column in your query, which you don't

```
st.executeQuery("SELECT Table1.key FROM Table1")
                                  ^-----------------column missing
```

Do

```
st.executeQuery("select key, itemName, itemPrice, itemQuantity from Table1")
```

Comment: it throws an error when I put
"SELECT Table1.key FROM Table1" instead of "SELECT * FROM Table1"

Comment: when I do it like:
"SELECT * FROM Table1" it works
"SELECT key, itemName, itemPrice, itemQuantity FROM Table1" also works
"SELECT key, itemName FROM Table1" this doesn't

Comment: If you `select *` you select **all** columns. If you `select key` you select **one** column. But since you need 2 columns, do `select key, itemName, itemPrice, itemQuantity from Table1`

Comment: ok I probably know where I'm wrong. I can't have in a while loop all of them to be printed out? Do I need to specify only the columns I selected, right?

Comment: Ok that is solved thanks @jurgen d

My last question is:
When I try to do

    "SELECT * FROM Table1 LIMIT 3"
it throws an error

    [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in FROM clause.

Comment: Acces does not support `limit`. That is MySQL syntax. Use `select top 3 key, itemname ...`

Comment: and I got my stuff printed out and after that is an error [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state

Comment: That is a different problem. If you can't solve it on your own, ask another question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

you should use 
buffer.append(rs.getString("Table1.key") + " ");

resultset have the data with name which you have given in select query.(key=Table1.key)

Comment: I tried and is an error as well. I can execute them all by put all the column names or using "*", but I can't do it just for one or two columns seperate

Comment: then use with table reference not table name... select t.key from table t